# Undo Operation in Matlab Linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I couldn't find  **Undo** Operation in Matlab Linux . Shortcut keys(matlab linux) for copy and paste are entirely different from windows version. Any **shortcut key for undo operation in matlab linux**?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the key bindings in the settings.

Home->Preferences->MATLAB->Keyboard->shortcuts->Active settings->Windows Default Set